# Give a name to \ref but not the name of the section - LaTex

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, nameref

I try to learn LaTex via TexStudio on Ubuntu.
I need to reference to a paragraph like that:

```
\paragraph{Théorème 5.}\label{theoreme5}
```

And I need that:

```
\section{Preuve du Théorème \nameref{theoreme5}}
```

But that print that (pdflatex):

[image]

It's all the name of the paragraph that is clickable.
But me I want to just have the "5" clickable (and put any number or word instead of the 5, if possible).

I'm not sure that I was clear. If someone can help me I will really gratefull.

Cordially

Comment: `\paragraph` os the 4th level section heading after section, subsection and subsubsection, it's more common to use a theorem environment declared with `\newtheorem` for theorems.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\hyperref[<internal link>]{<stuff>}` (with starred `\ref` inside `<stuff>`):

```
\section[Preuve du Théorème \ref*{theoreme5}]
  {Preuve du \hyperref[theoreme5]{Théorème \ref*{theoreme5}}}
```

The optional argument ensures that `\hyperref` doesn't sneak into the PDF bookmarks, which you can also do using `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\section{Preuve du 
  \texorpdfstring
    {\hyperref[theoreme5]{Théorème \ref*{theoreme5}}}% TeX string
    {Théorème \ref*{theoreme5}}}% PDF string
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you employ the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and its `\cref` user macro to achieve your typesetting goal. I would further suggest that you employ either the [amsthm](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) or [ntheorem](https://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package and their theorem-like environments instead of `\paragraph{...}` to generate, well, theorem-like environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{thm}{4} % just for this example
\begin{thm} \label{thm5} 
\dots 
\end{thm}

\dots

\stepcounter{section}
\section[Preuve du Théorème 5]{Preuve du \cref{thm5}}
\dots
\end{document}
```